# Linux mint - Media shortcuts working for banshee but not spotify

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, spotify, linux-mint

I have recently installed Linux mint, and installed Spotify (the preview version). I have set up some manual media shortcuts (play, next, ...) which seem to work fine with Banshee, but not Spotify.
Anyone has a solution how to make Spotify work with keyboard shortcuts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this quite successfully: https://github.com/jreese/spotify-gnome

It is likely someone will have already packaged this for apt-get so it might be worth having a google for it before doing a manual install.